# How to update asp.net core di container later on when some task is performed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, di-containers

I've kept settings values on di-container and settings can be changed through the  management page but when i again add new settings value in service collection it's giving me old settings values.
How to update di container values/service on .net core.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of injecting your strong-typed settings directly, you need to inject `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`, where `T` is your settings class. This will cause it update the values when the configuration is reloaded. For example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<MySettings> _settings;

    public MyController(IOptionsSnapshot<MySettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can alternatively set up the dependency injection to use `IOptionsSnapshot` directly:

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
services.AddScoped(cfg => cfg.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<MySettings>>().Value);
```

Then, you can continue to just inject `MySettings` into your controllers as before.

*Note: `IOptionsSnapshot` is available in ASP.NET Core 1.1+. There is no way to reload settings in any previous version.*